# Python sounddevice library is not recording sound on my ubuntu 22.04 Dell laptop

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-22.04, python-sounddevice

I'm running Visual Studio code on my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop. The code is very simple to record a piece of sound using the sound device library.

```
import sounddevice as sd

duration=10
fs=8000
my_record=sd.rec(fs*duration,samplerate=fs,channels=1)
sd.wait()
```

I do not get an error but no sound is recorded.

`sd.play(my_record,fs)`

plays blank.

What am I missing?

Comment: what does this have to do with VS Code? Does this only happen when you run from VS Code? Where and how exactly are you running from VS Code? Where else have you tried running it from? Are you running inside a Jupyter Notebook? What if you run from a Python file instead of a Notebook?

Comment: Check your hardware, or debug the code or print out the code to see if data is logged.

Comment: Tried with Jupyter Notebook and as a Python file as well. But I mainly run using VS Code. Neither of them are working.

Hardware is fine. I can record audio using other software. Or I can attend zoom or meet calls. The mic is not recording only using this code.

Comment: Will an error be reported if I directly use commands or other tools to execute the code? Does this only happen in vscode?